# Decreasing the page size when saving to PDF

Tags: inkscape, pdf, dpi

I created an SVG image in InkScpae. It is 1328 pixels wide.

Then I did "Save as PDF". The resulting PDF was 15 inch wide.

I need the PDF to be in the width of an A4 paper - about 8 inch.

I tried to play with the DPI setting, both while saving the PDF and in "File -> InkScape settings". I increased the DPI from 90 to 200 and to 300, but it did not change anything - the PDF is still too wide.

What can I do?

Comment: The DPI in the PDF export options is for the rasterization of filter effects, not the resulting PDF. The effects of many filters doesn't translate to PDF, so they are changed to a bitmap first during export.

Answer (score 3):

The "pixel" unity in SVG (or CSS) files is for reference only. Your image is never using actual pixels - they do not exist in vector formats such as SVG (the internal representation of Inkscape) or PDF files.

([Check the pixel defintion in CSS here](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html))

So, if you want your resulting image to be 210x297mm in size (A4), set 
*this* size in your document (`File->Document Properties`) - if you want a different aspect ratio but 210mm width, use a calculator and type the proper height in the `Custom Size` box in this dialog.

And finally, if you want "1328 pixels" in an exported raster (usually PNG) export of the same artwork, pick that amount of pixels on the "Export to PNG" dialog box. Only when this export is performed do actual pixels are created - and there 1328 pixels do have any sense. If you want the resulting PNG to have 1328 pixels wide, pick that value on raster-export.

If you for some reason need to work with 1328 width units, just do all your work, and prior to export, just resize everything so that the artwork will fit in 210mm: Set the document size as above, select all objects, and resize to fit. As you are working with a vector image, there is no data-loss in doing that.

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately something Inkscape cannot do. It sounds like what you're asking for is to have the image to have two difference sizes at once. Inkscape doesn't allow you to set the DPI of a PDF during export (the setting in the export window is the DPI for rasterizing filter effects, not the artwork itself), so you're stuck at 90 DPI.

The solution I would use is to change to image size to A4 in Inkscape and scale the artwork accordingly. If you have a hard requirement that it the SVG remain 1328, I don't think what you are trying to do can be accomplished in Inkscape.

One option would be to export your artwork to PNG, and then use Imagemagick to do the resizing. [See this topic](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=25693) in the Imagemagick forums for details.

Resizing a PNG *will* result in a loss of quality though. Unless your requirement that the SVG's width remain 1328, it would be much better to just re-size the vector. As others have stated, width for a vector graphic is relative.

Comment: -1 to export to png and them resize - that transforms the artwork into raster and will caus eloss of quality on resizing.

Comment: I provided that option as a word around to meet the requirements of this question. Obviously it's not ideal due to the quality loss, so I've edited the answer accordingly.