# Inkscape: Maintaining size when saving as PDF?

Tags: inkscape, pdf

when I save SVGs as PDFs from Inkscape, all dimensions seem to be decreased to 80% of their width.
For example, a 100 x 100 box, the PDF will be 80 x 80.

SVG:

```
    <rect
       y="280.93362"
       x="162.85715"
       height="100"
       width="100"
       id="rect3336"
       style="opacity:1;fill:#3023ae;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:1" />
  </g>
```

PDF:    `/MediaBox [ 0 0 80.800003 80.800003 ]`

I have tried experimenting with the resolution field, to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the page size? See [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58031/decreasing-the-page-size-when-saving-to-pdf).

Answer (score 1):

PDF base unit is 1/72th of an inch.

What you paste here for a SVG rect is in user units, and as such is meaningless without the root `<svg>` width, height and viewBox attributes (can you paste them as well?).

edit with `<svg viewBox="0 0 744.09448819 1052.3622047" height="297mm" width="210mm">`: 
744.09… user units correspond to 297mm==8.2677…in so basically in your document 90user units equal 1inch (value in pre-0.92 versions of Inkscape).

Supposing your rect is *not* in a scaled group hierarchy, its size is 100user units, ie 100/90=1.111… inch, ie 100/90*72=80"pt" (the pdf unit).

So everything is normal so far :)

To get a 100ptx100pt square, just use the "pt" units in Inkscape instead of "px" and it should work

Comment: You should also mention that PDF unit is Point, SVG unit is Pixel. Point is a fixed physical size, pixel is not.

Comment: @AAGD Actually, it depends : coordinates in the file elements are in "user units", but those can have either a relation to pixels (for most uses since svg is quite web-oriented) , or to physical sizes (or to neither), depending if the root svg document has an height in a physical unit or not ('px' or a relative unit like '%')

Comment: Gladly: <svg
   viewBox="0 0 744.09448819 1052.3622047"
   height="297mm"
   width="210mm">