# How do I set Inkscape-pdf-export to "fill viewport"

Tags: inkscape, pdf

I have an A4 (210x297 mm) svg in Inkscape.
When I export & open the pdf in Chrome, it isn't sized to fit the window -
it appears way too big and needs to be scrolled.
How would you advise me to fix/workaround this?
I want to avoid using a smaller size, so the pdf displays well on all screens.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, Ehdu Banunu. Can you tell us something more about the **Document properties** in Inkscape? Your question seems a duplicate of this: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58031/decreasing-the-page-size-when-saving-to-pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decreasing the page size when saving to PDF](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58031/decreasing-the-page-size-when-saving-to-pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I know from LibreOffice's pdf export that it is possible to set the initial view of a pdf file as a parameter inside the document (page layout (double pages, single, continuous scrolling)/show Table of Contents in a side bar/initial zoom).

For Inkscape, there exists no such option. Maybe it works if you open it in LibreOffice, and re-export as pdf?

Comment: To test your suggestion, I opened a PDF generated by Inkscape in LibreOffice Draw, then did Export as PDF, and set the Initial View as "Fit in Window", and it seems to work when viewing in Acrobat Reader. Great suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider installing this « ***SVGO-inkscape*** » plugin.
Juanfran, the author of the plugin:

https://github.com/juanfran/svgo-inkscape

> *The default Inkscape SVG files require a lot of inkscape metadata for edition purposes since SVG is the default file extension at inkscape. Using SVGO we can remove a lot of redundant and useless information such as editor metadata, comments, hidden elements, default or non-optimal values and other stuff that can be safely removed or converted without affecting SVG rendering result.*

NOTE: SVGO (SVG Optimizer) is a Nodejs-based tool for optimizing SVG vector graphics files.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Comment: Hi,. Welcome to GDSE.  Could you explain how the plugin can be used specifically for the problem the OP is facing. It's not clear how this plugin would fix the initial view size at which a PDF will be displayed when opened.

Comment: @BillyKerr : I don't have the exact answer regarding what parameter to use to adress the specific issue regarding PDF. But I use this plugin to remove parameters that sets the dimensions of my SVG files so they can fill a responsive container like a Bootstrap column.